# UTL_RAW INSTR function?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I was surprised that the Oracle raw type has a `SUBSTR` function but no `INSTR` function.

Is there a way to search for a sequence of bytes in a raw type as with the `INSTR` function in `varchar2` types?

Answer (score 1):

Write raw to blob and use blob instr ?

```
 DBMS_LOB.INSTR (lob_loc    IN   BLOB,
                 pattern    IN   RAW,`
                 offset     IN   INTEGER := 1,
                nth        IN   INTEGER := 1)
  RETURN INTEGER;
```

Comment: Yes, I can also convert the raw to a varchar2 and do the search there.

Answer (score 0):

Employ the `INSTRB` function.

Example (using the string 'hello ä there' as a utf8-encoded octet sequence) [result: 13]:

```
SELECT INSTRB ( utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2 ( HEXTORAW('68656c6c6F20C3A4207468657265') ), 'r' ) from dual;
```

Note that the octet sequence represented by the raw variable does not need to be a valid utf8 encoding.
Example ( replacing 'ä' encoding of 'C3A4' with 'C020' which is an illegal octet sequence in utf 8) [result: 13]:

```
SELECT INSTRB ( utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2 ( HEXTORAW('68656c6c6F20C020207468657265') ), 'r' ) from dual;
```

Tested on Oracle 12c1.